# Oracle Trigger NEW Keyword Is Not Working

Tags: json, oracle, rest, triggers, clob

I've created a trigger which retrieves individual JSON objects from CLOB column of another table, and inserts the JSON values into USERSESSIONS table as individual rows/columns.

These records also have JSON array inside them, such as Useractions or Stringproperties. You can see that I've used JSON_QUERY instead of JSON_VALUE for these columns in the main INSERT statement.

I also wanted to create another query which retrieves the Useractions CLOB array from USERSESSIONS table and use the last inserted row's ID as an indicator from USERSESSIONS table. For some reason :NEW.ID doesn't work. If I indicate this ID from USERSESSIONS table manually, this time it works, but this doesn't serve any purposes.

Basically what I am trying to accomplish;

1. Get CLOB record from UEM table.
2. Insert this record into individual columns in USERSESSIONS table.
3. Every single row inserted into USERSESSIONS table has its own CLOB column such as *Useractions*, which might contain multiple items as an array. So each time the second step above is triggered, I also would like to retrieve these arrays from USERSESSIONS table and insert them row by row into USERACTIONSTEST table.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER USERSESSIONS_INSERTION_TRIGGER
  AFTER INSERT ON UEM
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO USERSESSIONS
    (TENANTID,
     USERSESSIONID,
     STARTTIME,
     ENDTIME,
     DURATION,
     INTERNALUSERID,
     USERTYPE,
     REASONFORNOSESSIONREPLAY,
     REASONFORNOSESSIONREPLAYMOBILE,
     APPLICATIONTYPE,
     BOUNCE,
     NEWUSER,
     USERACTIONCOUNT,
     TOTALERRORCOUNT,
     TOTALLICENSECREDITCOUNT,
     MATCHINGCONVERSIONGOALSCOUNT,
     MATCHINGCONVERSIONGOALS,
     IP,
     CONTINENT,
     COUNTRY,
     REGION,
     CITY,
     BROWSERTYPE,
     BROWSERFAMILY,
     BROWSERMAJORVERSION,
     OSFAMILY,
     OSVERSION,
     MANUFACTURER,
     DEVICE,
     USERID,
     SCREENHEIGHT,
     SCREENWIDTH,
     SCREENORIENTATION,
     DISPLAYRESOLUTION,
     HASCRASH,
     CRASHGROUPID,
     HASSESSIONREPLAY,
     ISP,
     CLIENTTYPE,
     BROWSERMONITORID,
     BROWSERMONITORNAME,
     STRINGPROPERTIES,
     LONGPROPERTIES,
     DOUBLEPROPERTIES,
     DATEPROPERTIES,
     USERACTIONS,
     EVENTS,
     ERRORS,
     SYNTHETICEVENTS,
     APPVERSION,
     ENDREASON,
     NUMBEROFRAGECLICKS,
     NUMBEROFRAGETAPS,
     USEREXPERIENCESCORE,
     CARRIER,
     NETWORKTECHNOLOGY,
     CONNECTIONTYPE,
     REPLAYSTART,
     REPLAYEND,
     CLIENTTIMEOFFSET,
     ROOTEDORJAILBROKEN,
     HASERROR)
  VALUES
    ((JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.tenantId')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.userSessionId')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.startTime')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.endTime')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.duration')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.internalUserId')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.userType')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.reasonForNoSessionReplay')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.reasonForNoSessionReplayMobile')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.applicationType')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.bounce')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.newUser')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.userActionCount')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.totalErrorCount')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.totalLicenseCreditCount')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.matchingConversionGoalsCount')),
     (JSON_QUERY(:NEW.RECORD, '$.matchingConversionGoals' RETURNING CLOB)),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.ip')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.continent')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.country')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.region')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.city')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.browserType')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.browserFamily')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.browserMajorVersion')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.osFamily')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.osVersion')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.manufacturer')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.device')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.userId')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.screenHeight')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.screenWidth')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.screenOrientation')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.displayResolution')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.hasCrash')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.crashGroupId')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.hasSessionReplay')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.isp')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.clientType')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.browserMonitorId')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.browserMonitorName')),
     (JSON_QUERY(:NEW.RECORD, '$.stringProperties' RETURNING CLOB)),
     (JSON_QUERY(:NEW.RECORD, '$.longProperties' RETURNING CLOB)),
     (JSON_QUERY(:NEW.RECORD, '$.doubleProperties' RETURNING CLOB)),
     (JSON_QUERY(:NEW.RECORD, '$.dateProperties' RETURNING CLOB)),
     (JSON_QUERY(:NEW.RECORD, '$.userActions' RETURNING CLOB)),
     (JSON_QUERY(:NEW.RECORD, '$.events' RETURNING CLOB)),
     (JSON_QUERY(:NEW.RECORD, '$.errors' RETURNING CLOB)),
     (JSON_QUERY(:NEW.RECORD, '$.syntheticEvents' RETURNING CLOB)),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.appVersion')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.endReason')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.numberOfRageClicks')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.numberOfRageTaps')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.userExperienceScore')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.carrier')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.networkTechnology')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.connectionType')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.replayStart')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.replayEnd')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.clientTimeOffset')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.rootedOrJailbroken')),
     (JSON_VALUE(:NEW.RECORD, '$.hasError')));
  INSERT INTO USERACTIONSTEST
    (usersessionid, name, starttime)
    SELECT usersessionid, jt.name, jt.startTime
      FROM USERSESSIONS jte,
           JSON_TABLE(jte.USERACTIONS,
                      '$[*]' COLUMNS(
                                     name      PATH '$.name',
                                     startTime PATH '$.startTime'
                                    )
                      ) jt
     WHERE jte.ID = :NEW.ID; --<<===== THIS DOESN'T WORK
END USERSESSIONS_INSERTION_TRIGGER;
```

Comment: Okay, I've declared a variable and pulled the MAX(id) from the table. I don't know if that is the right way to do it, but it seems to work.

Comment: Can you explain a bit about what you mean when `:NEW.ID` "doesn't work"?  Do you get an error compiling the trigger, an error running the trigger, or does something else happen?

Comment: I don't get any errors. I have ORDS enabled. The main purpose of this trigger is to populate the tables by using the data from UEM table, which has two columns 1) ID (number) 2) RECORD (clob). This table is also populated via REST handlers. So when I post a json payload, I just get 200 OK, but USERACTIONSTEST table is not getting populated. If I use a specific ID from USERSESSIONS table, then it works. Workflow is like this --> POST JSON ----> UEM (clob) ----> USERSESSIONS ----> USERACTIONSTEST

Comment: So if no rows are being inserted into `USERACTIONSTEST` then the query within the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` statement is returning no rows.  The condition `jte.ID = :NEW.ID` looks odd to me: you are comparing an ID from the USERSESSIONS table with an ID from the `UEM` table.  Are these IDs always the same? If instead you want to grab the ID from the `INSERT` into the `USERSESSIONS` table (I'm guessing this is `GENERATED BY IDENTITY`?) , add a `RETURNING ID INTO l_some_variable` clause to this `INSERT` and use this local variable instead of `:NEW.ID`.